# How can I have a widget as a CellRenderer in gtk2hs?

Tags: haskell, gtk, gtk3, gtk2hs

I want to put a custom widget in my `TreeView` but `TreeViewColumn`s will only let me pack instances of `CellRenderer` and there is no instance that will let me just put any widget. Or maybe it's just not possible with gtk2hs?